# Building C++ CLR Managed DLL

Tags: c++, .net, managed

Can you help me resolve this error:

[image]

The values I am passing is a type String^ and I am actually passing the values in a template class but shows an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with it looks like you're trying to pass a managed memory 'username' to an unmanaged function.

```
String^ s = gcnew String("sample string");
IntPtr ip = Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(s);
const char* str = static_cast<const char*>(ip.ToPointer());

Console::WriteLine("(managed) passing string...");
NativeTakesAString( str );

Marshal::FreeHGlobal( ip );
```

reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/22e4dash.aspx

Comment: There's a bunch of helpers for marshaling common types like strings. I've updated my answer with one I found doing a quick search.

Comment: By the way, I highly recommend doing as little program logic as possible in this boundary between managed and unmanaged code. Try to keep the data that has to cross the border to a minimum and just write calls to marshal the data over the boundary in this, which maybe you're already doing... just in case though ;)